# How to make window size observable using knockout

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

Trying to do something about the browser window:

1. Is it possible to make the window size (`$(window).width(), $(window).height()`) observable using Knockout?
2. How to keep **FUTURE Added Elements** in the center of the window? Is there something can be done using the **jquery live method** or the **knockout custom bindings**?

Any Suggestion appreciated!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The only way to make them observable is to proxy them into observable properties.

```
var yourViewModel = {
   width: ko.observable(),
   height: ko.observable()
};

var $window = $(window);
$window.resize(function () { 
    yourViewModel.width($window.width());
    yourViewModel.height($window.height());
});
```

I don't really understand your second question. Couldn't you just use css for this?

**EDIT**

Second question. One possibility would be write a binding handler to do this (untested).

```
ko.bindingHandlers.center {
   init: function (element) {
       var $el = $(element);

       $el.css({ 
           left: "50%", 
           position: "absolute", 
           marginLeft: ($el.width() / 2) + 'px' 
       }); 
   }
}
```

The 50% and margin-left is a great way to center things in your scenarios since it automatcially works even if the window is resized. Obviously if the divs themselves resize you need to recalculate the left margin, this could always be bound to a value on the viewmodel.
Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, find a better way: `ko.bindingHandlers.winsize = {
        init: function (element, valueAccessor) {
            $(window).resize(function () {
                var value = valueAccessor();
                value({ width: $(window).width(), height: $(window).height() });
            });
        }`

Comment: The second question, eg.: using jquery to add several div elements(absolute position, different width&height) to the doc, at the same time keep them in the center of the browser window(so, need to calculate the css left and css height of each div dynamically), further more, if the window resize event happens, recalculate...still trying.

Comment: @Dean How do you use the winsize binding handler, I need to call a custom method every time window size changes, tx

Answer (score 1):

To elaborate on Dean's comment of his `winsize` custom bindingHandler, this is how it can be used:

**JS**

```
ko.bindingHandlers.winsize = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor) {
        $(window).resize(function () {
            var value = valueAccessor();
            value({ width: $(window).width(), height: $(window).height() });
        });
    }
}

self.windowSize = ko.observable();
```

**HTML**

```
<div data-bind="winsize: windowSize"></div>
```